# How to fetch data from database using serialize object in where clause

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am storing one class as serialize object in Database in JPA.
Now I am going to fetch that data using serialize object in where clause.

Below is my serialize object class

`

```
    public class Candidates implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6852589184246588241L;

    Long id;
    String firstname;
    String lastname;
    String email;
    String address;
    String phone;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }
}
```

`

And below is entity class where I'm storing serialize obejct

`

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.Lob;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import com.rms.vo.Candidates;

import lombok.Data;

@Entity
@Table(name = "candidate")
@Data
public class Candidate extends Auditable implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "candidate_sequence")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "candidate_sequence", sequenceName = "candidate_sequence", allocationSize = 50)
    @Column(name = "candidate_id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="userId")
    private User user;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Lob
    @Column(name = "resume")
    private Serializable resume;



    public Candidates getResume() {
        return (Candidates) resume;
    }

    public void setResume(Candidates resume) {
        this.resume = resume;
    }       
}
`
```

and I m using below method to fetch data but its giving kindly help me to solve this issue

`

```
@Query("from Candidate where resume.firstname='Mujahid' or resume.firstname='MUJAHID' ")
    public List<Candidate> getCandidateListByName();
```

'

I m getting below error

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
24-11-2018 10:40:58.152 [restartedMain] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication.reportFailure - Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'candidateRestController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'candidateService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'candidateService': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'candidateRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.rms.repository.CandidateRepository.getCandidateListByName()!
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:587)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:91)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:373)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1344)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:388)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1234)
        at com.rms.RMSMain.main(RMSMain.java:12)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'candidateService': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'candidateRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.rms.repository.CandidateRepository.getCandidateListByName()!
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:321)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1344)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:584)
        ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'candidateRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.rms.repository.CandidateRepository.getCandidateListByName()!
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1710)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:583)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:205)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.autowireResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:513)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.getResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:484)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$ResourceElement.getResourceToInject(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:618)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:177)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:91)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:318)
        ... 35 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.rms.repository.CandidateRepository.getCandidateListByName()!
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:93)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.<init>(SimpleJpaQuery.java:63)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromMethodWithQueryString(JpaQueryFactory.java:76)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromQueryAnnotation(JpaQueryFactory.java:56)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$DeclaredQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:139)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:206)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:79)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:553)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$mapMethodsToQuery$1(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:546)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
        at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
        at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.forEachRemaining(Collections.java:1049)
        at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
        at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.mapMethodsToQuery(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:548)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$new$0(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:538)
        at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:538)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:317)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$3(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:287)
        at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:141)
        at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:63)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:290)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:102)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1769)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1706)
        ... 47 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: firstname of: com.rms.entity.Candidate [from com.rms.entity.Candidate where resume.firstname='Mujahid' or resume.firstname='MUJAHID' ]
        at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:133)
        at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:157)
        at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:164)
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:670)
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:23)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:350)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy141.createQuery(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:87)
        ... 76 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: firstname of: com.rms.entity.Candidate [from com.rms.entity.Candidate where resume.firstname='Mujahid' or resume.firstname='MUJAHID' ]
        at org.hibernate.QueryException.generateQueryException(QueryException.java:120)
        at org.hibernate.QueryException.wrapWithQueryString(QueryException.java:103)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:217)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:141)
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:115)
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:77)
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:153)
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:553)
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:662)
        ... 84 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: firstname of: com.rms.entity.Candidate
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.propertyException(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:71)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.toType(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:65)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.toType(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1859)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElementType.getPropertyType(FromElementType.java:393)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElement.getPropertyType(FromElement.java:512)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.DotNode.getDataType(DotNode.java:687)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.DotNode.prepareLhs(DotNode.java:270)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.DotNode.resolve(DotNode.java:210)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.resolve(HqlSqlWalker.java:1040)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.expr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1290)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.exprOrSubquery(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:4717)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.comparisonExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:4185)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2138)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2088)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.whereClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:815)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:609)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:313)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:261)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:266)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:189)
        ... 90 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Can you post the error stacktrace? You don't explain what the error is in your question

Comment: Can you boild it down to a *minimal verifyable example* and add the error output and expected behaviour as by the good-questions guidelines?

Comment: You know this cast thing you have going on in the JPQL ... there is no such CAST in JPQL. JPQL has "TREAT"